# Rotate an imageView without changing its size Android

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

i want to orate multiple time an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout. 
To do so i use :

```
    angleRotation = angleRotation + (float)90; 

         Rect bounds = imgToRotate.getDrawable().getBounds();

        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        imgToRotate.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
        matrix.postRotate((float) angleRotation,  bounds.width() / 2 , bounds.height() / 2);
        imgToRotate.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

The problem is that the matrix i use change the size of my ImageView. i do not know how not to change the size.

Any help ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean that the image changes size so its scaled down/up? Or the image isn't square and you mean that newWidth = oldHeight && newHeight = oldWidth ?

Comment: i mean that the image keeps ratio but it is scaled down.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use a xml file to create a rotate animation ?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: i need to write this image to file do you think if i use the rotation the image will be rotated after writing ?

Comment: I am not really sure to understand the question actually.

Comment: i want to write my image to cache, i wonder if a apply a rotation animation if the image will have the rotation applied once i wrote it to cache.

Comment: Oh, then no I don't think so, but I know there is a way to call a function when an animation just end so maybe you can get some information but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I use in one of my apps to rotate the image based on the bitmap.

```
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.preRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
```

After that you can set the image bitmap into the imageView.
I assume that you can keep (or get) a reference to your original bitmap.

Edit:
If you target API 11 and up you can use method:

```
View.setRotation(float angle);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yea i already have tried this way, the problem is that i get a grow heap each time i create a new bitmap.

Comment: What API are you targetting?

Comment: Devices with API Level 10, are a few percent. I would suggest implementing 2 solutions, View.setRotation(float angle) for most devices and using the Matrix for the devices with api level 10.

Comment: your code resize my image, what w and h should be ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. Should be the originalBitmap width & height (or whatever suits you better).